# How to hide text formatting popup (Mini Toolbar) in Microsoft Word 2007

Tags: microsoft-word, formatting

In Microsoft Word 2007 when you select a piece of text, a pop-up toolbar will display containing the common font formatting tools like font-name, font-size, bold, italic, etc. (The Mini Toolbar.)

Is there a way to prevent this pop-up from showing when you select text?

Comment: OMG this f***ing bar!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Hit the Office button.

Choose Word Options.

In the "Options" → "Popular" window
("Options" → "General" in newer versions of Word),
uncheck the "Show Mini Toolbar on selection" option:

[image: Word 1909 Version]

Answer (score 3):

If I understood correctly what exactly you wish to disable, then [these](http://www.nirmaltv.com/2008/10/10/how-to-disable-mini-toolbar-in-ms-word-2007/) are the instructions on how to do it.

In short, Round button / Word Options / Remove the checkmark on "Show Mini toolbar on Selection".

Answer (score 1):

For someone who is looking for this solution for Word 2019

File > Options > General -> Unchek Show Mini Toolbar on selection.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question as the OP and landed here to find the answer.  I sometimes do better with pictures, in case anyone else does too.

[image: How to get rid of mini bar pop-up]