# Disabling Microsoft Word's Formatting Pop-Up

Tags: microsoft-word

When one selects text in Microsoft Word, a small box pops up containing a font drop-down, bold/italic/underline buttons, and a small number of other formatting tools from the Home tab. The box only disappears when the cursor is moved away from it. How do I stop this box from appearing? I personally never use the box; it just gets in the way whenever I want to reread the text I've just selected.

[image]

*An example of this dialog box impeding the text. Come to think of it, I would find it useful to get rid of the "paste/(Ctrl)" drop-down as well.*

Comment: Look in Word Options, Advanced and check the options there. Look then in Ease of Access and uncheck Show Shortcut Keys in Screen Tips. I often use these functions in Word so I do not disable them

Comment: @John This is not the feature I am referring to. I updated my post to clarify.

Comment: The formatting box is part of the Office / Word evolution. That is the Mini Toolbar.  I do not see a specific option for this. Look in Word Options under Display and Advanced to see if anything removes this. Document Tooltips on Hover might. Shortcut Keys in Screen Tips might. It is a right context feature and I just ignore it.

Comment: @John Thank you for your help. Now that I know what the feature is called, I can work from there.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is called the Mini Toolbar. Follow the steps at [this link](https://superuser.com/questions/183468/how-to-hide-text-formatting-popup-mini-toolbar-in-microsoft-word-2007?rq=1) to disable or re-enable the Mini Toolbar.